# Change property access based on template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have a base class that is a template that looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    T bar;
};
```

What I'd like to do is introduce a template argument that can be used to control the access mode of the member bar.

Something like this:

```
template <typename T,bool publicBar=true>
class Foo
{

public: 
    // If publicBar is false, insert protected: here
    T bar;
};
```

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Edit:
Many asked so, for those interesting in why I'm doing this, here's my real code!

```
    // Class used for automatic setter/getter generation.
template <typename T,publicSetter=true>
class Property
{
public:
    Property(){}
    Property(T value):mObject(object){}
    T operator()()const
    {
        return mObject;
    }
public: // This is where I want the protected:
    virtual void operator()(T newObject)
    {
        this->mObject = newObject;
    }
private:
    T mObject;
};
```

Comment: Protected? You intend users to inherit from `Property<T>`, meaning that using classes may only have a single `Property` of each type?

Comment: Nope, users will create instances of it as members in their classes. However I have some specialized classes in mind that will inherit from Property that will need access to the setter.

Comment: Is there a problem you're aiming to solve? From what I've seen so far, you're going to end up with code far more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: As far as I can see, you can always just replace the `Property` object itself, if you want to reassign `mObject`, so I don't see the point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done using partial template specialization:

```
template <typename T,bool publicBar>
class Foo
{
};

template <typename T>
class Foo<T,true>
{
public: 
    T bar;
};

template <typename T>
class Foo<T,false>
{
protected: 
    T bar;
};
```

The only gotcha here is that you would need to replicate the entire class for each specialization... **UNLESS** you wanted to make it on top of a base class, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
class FooBase
{
    //the goods go here
};

template <typename T,bool publicBar>
class Foo : public FooBase<T>
{
};

template <typename T>
class Foo<T,true> : public FooBase<T>
{
public: 
    T bar;
};

template <typename T>
class Foo<T,false> : public FooBase<T>
{
protected: 
    T bar;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is *possible* using partial specialization. Whether it's advisable is a another question - for a start, this solution doesn't scale as you need 2^n specializations where n is the number of variables you're controlling the access of. And do you really want the interface of your class to change based on the value of a template parameter?

It seems like you're creating something difficult to maintain, difficult to understand and overly clever.

Nevertheless, if you decide this is a good idea, here's how you would do it:

```
template <typename T, bool publicBar=true>
class Foo
{
public:
  T bar;
};

template <typename T>
class Foo<T,false>
{
protected:
  T bar;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using explicit class template specialization:

```
template<bool B> class Foo;

template<> class Foo<true>
{
public: 
    int n_;
};

template<> class Foo<false>
{
protected:
    int n_;
};

int main()
{
    Foo<true> fa;
    fa.n_;
    Foo<false> fb;
    fb.n_;  // ERROR: protected
}
```

Seems like a really bad idea, though.  Why would you want to?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this with a template specialization. Totally untested code.

```
template <typename T,bool publicBar=true>
class Foo
{

public: 
    // If publicBar is false, insert protected: here
    T bar;
};

template <typename T, false>
class Foo
{

protected: 
    // If publicBar is false, insert protected: here
    T bar;
};
```

But really consider why you'd want to do this. `public` data is really dangerous for encapsulation, and `protected` is nearly so. A solution that's able to utilize a client-API will probably be more maintainable in the long-term.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
template<typename T>
struct FooBase {
    T bar;
};

template<typename T, bool publicBar>
class Foo : public FooBase<T> {};

template<typename T>
class Foo<T, false> : protected FooBase<T> {};
```

This way you don't have to define `bar` a number of times but only once.